# Permission denied while installing packages

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, next.js, npm-install

I have a Next JS project cloned using a personal access token from GitHub.

When I run `npm i` I'm getting a permission denied error. There are two private packages mentioned in the dependency list.

[image]

Later, I tried to install packages after adding `_authToken` in `.npmrc`. I'm still getting the below error.

[image]

I have also checked that my Personal Access Token has `packages:read` permissions.

I'm expecting to install these private packages.

**Updates:**

I have solved the issue.

I have authenticated my Google account using the `google-artifactregistry-auth` package. It fetched my credentials and secrets and provided access to the artefact registry.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons you may be seeing this error:

- The package simply does not exist, maybe you have made a typo when entering the dependency name.
- You do not have sufficient access rights do download the packages contents, maybe it is a private package or scoped to the containing organization.

I personally think the first option is much more likely.

Comment: I have authenticated my Google account using the google-artifactregistry-auth package. It fetched my credentials and secrets and provided access to the artefact registry. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The package you are trying to install is using the Google Artifact Registry. So you need to log in to Cloud CLI first and then authenticate your permissions with google-artefactregistry-auth to fetch credentials and secrets.

Now you can try to install your packages. I think it should work properly.

Do check that you have properly configured your `.npmrc` file.

Comment: Yes, you are right as I have mentioned in the question updates, I have solved it the same way you suggested.